# What is in bash var=64#@_

Tags: bash

I have the net line

```
let "b64 = 64#@_" # the result is 4011    
echo "b64 = $b64" # is 4011
```

How did we get this result.
Does anybody knows what base notation is and how we got this result? Where can I read about this notation?

Answer (score 5):

According to `man bash` in the third paragraph under ARITHMETIC EXPANSION:

> If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used.  When specifying n, the digits greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, @, and _, in that order.  If base is less than or equal  to  36,  lowercase and  uppercase  letters  may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35.

There are only 62 digits in the alphabet a-z + A-Z + 0-9. Two more are needed. So @ and _ are just digits in a base 64 representation of a number.

```
$ echo "$(( 64#@ ))"
62
$ echo "$(( 64#_ ))"
63
$ echo "$(( 64#@@ ))"
4030
$ echo "$(( 64#@_ ))"
4031
```

I can't quite explain the result of "4011". I believe it's just a typo in your question.

Comment: I understand that number before # is number. However my question is where can I get a table with notation - &,@._ and so on

Comment: @osamuyl 0-9 are 0-9 respectively. a-z are 10-35. A-Z are 36-61. @ is 62. _ is 63. Since 64 is the largest radix that bash can handle, no other characters are allowed.

Comment: Got it. The question is closed

Comment: @osamuyl you can mark an answer as correct by clicking the green checkmark next to that answer. That will complete the Q/A.

Answer (score 4):

If you type `help let`, bash will tell you about the `let` command. It tells bash to evaluate each argument as an arithmetic expression.

[The bash reference manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) explains what `64#@_` means:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading ‘`0x`’ or ‘`0X`’ denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form *[base#]n*, where the optional *base* is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and *n* is a number in that base. If *base#* is omitted, then base 10 is used. When specifying *n*, the digits greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, ‘`@`’, and ‘`_`’, in that order. If base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35.

So your command assigns a numeric value to the variable named `b64`. The numeric value is given in base 64. In bash's base 64, `@` is the digit with value 62, and `_` is the digit with value 63, so the total value is 62×64<sup>1</sup> + 63×64<sup>0</sup> = 4031.

(Note that you incorrectly stated that the result is 4011. I tested with bash version 4.2.48(1)-release and got 4031.)